# how to embed tabpanel under another tabpanel in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I built a simple example, ui1 is based on (shiny) navbarPage, and in ui2 i used shiny dashboardpage .
In ui1 i was able to present tabPanels under each other using tabsetPanel , in shiny dashboard i could not do the same thing. 
How to implement the tabsetPanel as in ui1 example in shiny dashboard Page ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

  ui1 = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tabPanel("Main1",
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("tab1","TAB1"),
                 tabPanel("tab2","TAB2")
               )),
      tabPanel("Main2",textOutput("text"))

    )
  )
  ui2=navbarPage("tabBoxes",
                tabPanel("Main1",
                         tabsetPanel(
                           tabPanel("tab1","TAB1"),
                           tabPanel("tab2","TAB2")
                         )),
                tabPanel("Main2",textOutput("text"))
                )

  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$text <- renderText({
      paste("hi")
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui=ui1,server=server)
  shinyApp(ui=ui2,server=server)
```